# Why do I keep getting this error message; IndexError: index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100

Tags: python

This is the snippet of code that is causing the issue:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = 100

a_1 = np.arange(start=0,stop=(1/15)**(1/3)+0.0001,step=0.0001)
b_1 = np.empty((len(a_1),x),dtype=object)
g4 = np.empty((len(a_1),x))
g6 = np.empty((len(a_1),x))
g4min = np.empty((1,len(a_1)))
g6min = np.empty((1,len(a_1)))
g4max = np.empty((1,len(a_1)))
g6max = np.empty((1,len(a_1)))
b1 = np.empty((1,len(a_1)))

np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')

diter = 1/x

iter = np.arange(0, x, diter)

for n in range(0,len(a_1)+1):
     b1[n] = (-8*a_1[n]**3+1+(96*a_1[n]**6-16*a_1[n]**3+1)**(1/2))**(1/3)/(2**(1/3))-a_1[n]-     (2*(2)**(1/3)*a_1[n]**2)/(-8*a_1[n]**3+1+(96*a_1[n]**6-16*a_1[n]**3+1)**(1/2))**(1/3)/x
     h = 0
     for j in range(0,len(iter)+1):
        b_1[n][j] = b1[n]*h
        h = h+1
```

I know that there is an issue with the with how I have defined the for loops for b_1 and b1 but I cannot seem to find it. Thanks.

Comment: Use this : for n in range(len(a_1))

Comment: Array indices start at 0. So an array of length 100 has valid indices of 0 through 99. Index 100 is out of range. This is probably incorrect: `range(0,len(iter)+1)`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have tried all of these before and I still get the same error code.

Answer (score 1):

Python arrays start at 0 and end at length -1. Your array has 100 elements, and the last index is thus 99. For an array of 101 then you would have last index be 100.